# I'm building Connect Four game in terminal but cannot find four adjacent elements of a line

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't know how to debug that piece of code at the beginning of `diagonal1(grid)` method down to where the static method `checkWin()` ends, because when I run debugger it immediately closes and doesn't even reach the method `checWin()`. **The only thing i don't understand is why the innermost `for` loop that iterates over `line` returns an empty array instead of, for example, `['X', 'X', 'X', 'X']`.** I need that `for` loop to look for four similar adjacent elements and return an array with them inside.

**My code**:

```js
class Myclass {
  consructor() {
    this.playerTurn = "O";
    this.grid = [[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
                 [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
                 [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
                 [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
                 [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
                 [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']]

    this.cursor = new Cursor(6, 7);

    // Initialize a 6x7 connect-four grid
    Screen.initialize(6, 7);
    Screen.setGridlines(true);

    // Replace this with real commands
    Screen.addCommand('up', 'move up', this.cursor.up);
    Screen.addCommand('down', 'move down', this.cursor.down);
    Screen.addCommand('right', 'move right', this.cursor.right);
    Screen.addCommand('left', 'move left', this.cursor.left);

    this.cursor.setBackgroundColor();
    Screen.render();
  }

  diagonal1(grid) {
    let diagonals = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
        let diagonal = [];

        let row = i;
        let col = j;
        while (row < grid.length && col < grid[i].length) {
          diagonal.push(grid[row][col]);
          row++;
          col++;
        }
        if (diagonal.length > 4) {
          diagonals.push(diagonal);
        }
      }
    }
    return diagonals;
  }

  diagonal2(grid) {
    let diagonals = [];

    for (let i = grid.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      for (let j = grid[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        let diagonal = [];

        let row = i;
        let col = j;
        while (row >= 0 && col >= 0) {
          diagonal.push(grid[row][col]);
          row--;
          col--;
        }
        if (diagonal.length > 4) {
          diagonals.push(diagonal);
        }
      }
    }
    return diagonals;
  }

  static checkWin(grid) {
    const players = ['X', 'O'];
    const columns = grid[0].map((_, i) => grid.map(row => row[i]));
    const rows = grid;
    const obj = new ConnectFour();
    const downwardDiagonals = obj.diagonal1(grid);
    const upwardDiagonals = obj.diagonal2(grid);

    if (grid.flat().every(cell => cell === ' ')) {
      return false;
    }

    for (let player of players) {
      let winner = [];
      for (let line of [...rows, ...columns, ...downwardDiagonals, ...upwardDiagonals]) {
        // find the player that takes four cells of a line consequtively
        let currentElement = [];
        let count = 0;
        let winner = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
          if (line[i] !== ' ' && line[i] === currentElement) {
            count++;
          } else {
            currentElement = line[i];
            count = 0;
          }
          if (count >= 4) {
            winner.push(currentElement);
          }
        }
        console.log(winner)
        return winner;
      }
      // ------------------------------
      if (winner.length >= 4) return player;
      
      if (grid.flat().every(cell => cell !== ' ')) {
        return "T";
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  static endGame(winner) {
    if (winner === 'O' || winner === 'X') {
      Screen.setMessage(`Player ${winner} wins!`);
    } else if (winner === 'T') {
      Screen.setMessage(`Tie game!`);
    } else {
      Screen.setMessage(`Game Over`);
    }
    Screen.render();
    Screen.quit();
  }
}
```

what the tests get back:

1. Connect Four
   recognizes horizontal wins:
   AssertionError: expected [] to equal 'X'
   at Context. (test/connect-four-spec.js:31:43)
   at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)
2. Connect Four
   recognizes vertical wins:
   AssertionError: expected [] to equal 'X'
   at Context. (test/connect-four-spec.js:53:43)
   at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)
3. Connect Four
   recognizes diagonal downward wins:
   AssertionError: expected [] to equal 'X'
   at Context. (test/connect-four-spec.js:76:43)
   at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)
4. Connect Four
   recognizes diagonal upward wins:
   AssertionError: expected [] to equal 'O'
   at Context. (test/connect-four-spec.js:89:43)

Comment: Hey Ali :) The code you posted was invalid and formatted in a very difficult to read way. I'd advise generally working on your question a little more carefully when posting, you'll most likely get more people to help if your question is well organized and spell checked etc :)

Comment: There are actually multiple multiple issues with the code so it's really really hard to actually start to parse it. You don't give an example of exactly how are you calling the code. Also, what is "Screen"? Node doesn't have an API called Screen that I can see. Also, what is calling `diagonal1` and the other functions? Also, what is the grid that you are giving `diagonal1`? If you are giving `diagonal1` a grid, why do you _also_ have a property called grid?